# Why is extra Start-Sleep needed after submit button click but not after Navigate (in PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, browser-automation

In examples of automating IE using PowerShell I see the following:

```
$ie.Navigate($url)
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
```

Which makes sense. But then, I see:

```
$ie.Document.getElementById($submitButtonElementId).click()
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
Start-Sleep -m 2000
```

Why is the extra `Start-Sleep` needed in the second example? I've noticed that all similar example scripts I've come across have that after doing a `btn.click()`, while it is not included after an `$ie.Navigate($url)`. Furthermore, the time "slept" is seemingly arbitrary, as I've seen 1, 2, 5 seconds, etc. I tried my script with and without the extra `Start-Sleep` line, and it only works when it's included. Why? And, what is the appropriate time to sleep (or is it trial and error based on the web page being loaded)?

Comment: My guess is that IE returns a valid `ReadyState` before it actually can accept more input.  This could be tested by leaving the window this process creates visible (`$ie.visible = $true`) and adding some console output immediately after the while loop ends.  If you get the console message before the page visibly loads then that proves it.

Comment: I guess I assumed it was something like that. It's just odd that it's needed after simulating a submit button click, but not after invoking `$ie.Navigate($url)`.